How to get order id from customer billing email with a Python script - WooCommerce API
I would like to create a Python script that returns the orders of a customer, knowing only his billing email.
I tried doing this but returns all recent orders:
from woocommerce import API

wcapi = API(
    url="https://siteexample.com",
    consumer_key="ck_xxx",
    consumer_secret="cs_xxx",
    version="wc/v3"
)

response = wcapi.get("orders", params={"billing": {"email": "example@email.com"}}).json()
print(response)

I also saw from the official WooCommerce documentation that you can retrieve orders directly from the customer ID.
Then how can I get the customer ID knowing his billing email?

anyone? :( Maybe there’s not a viable solution?
